# Morphisms in category $Def(T)$

Tags: model-theory

Anand Pillay in the beautiful introduction of one of his papers says: " There are various invariants of a first-order theory $T$ ". ... He goes on to say " Another invariant is $Def(T)$, The category of definable sets. $Def (T)$ can be thought of syntactically or semantically. Syntactically the objects are formulas $\phi(\bar{x})$ .... The morphisms are given by formulas
$\psi(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ such that $T$ says that $\psi$ is the graph of a (partial) function ".

May you please give me an intuition as to why the morphisms look like this? I mean why are they defined that way.

Answer (score 1):

In the category $Def(T)$ the objects are definable sets and the morphisms are definable functions (in models of $T$).  Thus if we think syntactically, a morphism should be a formula that $T$ knows defines a function.  That is, it should be a formula $\psi(\overline{x}, \overline{y})$ such that $T \models \forall \overline{x}\,\exists!\,\overline{y} \phi(\overline{x}, \overline{y})$.

The parenthetical (partial) is allowing that we might actually only ask that our morphism be a function with domain some definable set, rather than the whole universe of the model of $T$.  That is, we could ask that $\psi$ defines a function when $\vec{x}$ is restricted to come from some definable set; so we might have some other formula $\phi(\overline{x})$ such that $T \models \forall \overline{x} (\phi(\overline{x}) \to \exists! \overline{y}\,\psi(\overline{x}, \overline{y}))$.